# how to set startDate to beginning of the month in bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have two text field one for start date and one for end date.
For start date i want to set beginning of the month as default. But not getting how to accomplish that.

This is my code

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'bootstrap-datepicker.js'%>

<%= form_tag '/mine', :class => "form-inline" do %>
 <%= label_tag 'start_date', 'Start Date' %>
 <%= text_field_tag 'start_date', nil, :class => 'calendar1' %>
 <%= label_tag 'end_date', 'End Date' %>
 <%= text_field_tag 'end_date', nil, :class => 'calendar' %>
<% end %>

<script>
$(".calendar").datepicker({format: "dd/mm/yyyy"});
$(".calendar1").datepicker({format: "dd/mm/yyyy"});
</script>
```

I tried like this by referring [here](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/options.html)

```
$(".calendar1").datepicker({format: "dd/mm/yyyy", startDate: Date.today.beginning_of_month});
or
$(".calendar1").datepicker({format: "dd/mm/yyyy",setDate date(Date.today.beginning_of_month)});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'start_date', Date.today.beginning_of_month.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'), :class => 'calendar1' %>
```